# Como substituir virgula por ponto de um df inteiro sem precisar fazer coluna por coluna - Python

Tags: python

tenho o seguinte código:

```
df10['Total_Forecast'] = df10['Total_Forecast'].apply(lambda x: float(x.replace(".","").replace(",",".")))
```

Está funcionando, mas eu preciso aplicar o replace coluna por coluna do df10. Já tentei tirar o nome da coluna, mas o código não funciona para varrer todas as colunas do df10 que tem virgula, virar ponto. Tem algum jeito de fazer isso para o df inteiro?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

é só aplicar a regra em todo dataframe

### Criando dataframe teste

```
>>> import pandas as pd

>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"A": ["Teste com, virgula", "Outro, teste"], "B": ["Nada aqui", "Mas, aqui tem"], "C": [1, 2]})
```

### O dataframe

```
>>> df
                    A              B    C
0  Teste com, virgula      Nada aqui  1.0
1        Outro, teste  Mas, aqui tem  2.2
```

### Convertendo

```
df1 = df.replace({',': '.'}, regex=True)
```

### O Resultado

```
>>> df1
                    A              B    C
0  Teste com. virgula      Nada aqui  1.0
1        Outro. teste  Mas. aqui tem  2.2
```

Comment: Mas nesse caso, se eu tiver colunas que não tem virgulas, mas são colunas int, retornou NaN. Por que?

Comment: Atualizado de acordo com seu comentário.

Comment: Funcionou! Obrigada!!! :D